Metaspades is not working with a for-loop in several files
I'm trying to create a for-loop to run metaspades, I have around 200 files, 100 of samples, each sample has two files and the files are named like this sample1_R1.fq.gz and sample1_R2.fq.gz), I need to run these files by chunks of 26 samples, so I did this:
#!/bin/bash

# Define directories
Read_DIR="/path/to/read_directory"
Assembly_DIR="/path/to/assembly_directory"

# Generate sample IDs from sample1 to sample26
sample_ids=()
for i in {1..26}; do
  sample_ids+=("sample$i")
done

# Generate sample IDs from sample1 to sample26
sample_ids=()
for i in {1..26}; do
  sample_ids+=("sample$i")
done

# Iterate over each sample ID and run metaspades.py
for sample_id in "${sample_ids[@]}"; do
  # Construct the input file names
  file_1="${Read_DIR}/${sample_id}_clean_1.fq.gz"
  file_2="${Read_DIR}/${sample_id}_clean_2.fq.gz"

  # Construct the output directory
  output_dir="$Assembly_DIR/${sample_id}_ass"

  # Run the metaspades.py command
  metaspades.py -1 $file_1 -2 $file_2 -o $output_dir -t 15 -m 230 -k 30
done

It works with the first sample, when it passes to the second sample is not working and appears this:
== Error ==  file not found: /path/to/read_directory/sample2_R1.fq.gz (left reads, library number: 1, library type: paired-end)

In case you have troubles running SPAdes, you can write to spades.support@cab.spbu.ru
or report an issue on our GitHub repository github.com/ablab/spades
Please provide us with params.txt and spades.log files from the output directory.

but the path is well constructed, do you know how can I fix this?
I saw others publications like this, but it seems I have something similar.
